# Generate summed up ranges from a list

Tags: python, list, range

I have a list of integers:

```
list = [a,b,c,d]
```

I would like to convert it to these ranges:

```
0..a
a+1..a+b
a+b+1..a+b+c
a+b+c+1..a+b+c+d
```

Any ideas how to do this in python?

Thanks

Comment: Are those the ranges you actually want?

Comment: keep in mind you probably don't want to name your list "list" since its a built in python object.

Comment: @Hoopdady Yes thanks for that...I named it list for clarification.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer instead of the one provided by @mgilson. Mine covers negative numbers as input as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple generator will do:

```
def to_ranges(seq):
    iseq = iter(seq)
    x = next(iseq)
    yield range(0,x+1)
    start = x
    for x in iseq:
        stop = start+x
        yield range(start+1,stop+1)
        start = stop


for x in to_ranges([1,2,3,4]):
    print x
```

This gives:

```
[0, 1]         #0 .. a check
[2, 3]         #a+1 (2) .. a+b (1+2=3) check 
[4, 5, 6]      #a+b+1 (1+2+1=4) .. a+b+c (1+2+3=6) check
[7, 8, 9, 10]  #a+b+c+1 (1+2+3+1=7) .. a+b+c+d (1+2+3+4=10) check
```

finally got it right.  The unfortunate thing here is that the first loop is special because of the 0 boundary condition -- so we just need to unroll that one and all is right with the world.

Comment: I haven't finished my morning coffee, but this doesn't seem to produce the results the OP is requesting.

Comment: @root -- Yeah.  It was unfortunately not quiet that easy.  I think I've got it right now (although check me -- I haven't had my morning coffee either ...)

Comment: Not really, as the output should be [0..1][2..3][3..6][7..10]

Comment: @bioinf80 -- Other than `[4..6]` instead of `[3..6]` (and I assert that the `4` is correct), isn't that what I have?

Comment: @root -- Finally.  that one was harder than it seemed on the surface.  I'm still wondering if I could do better iterating over `itertools.chain([-1],seq)` or something similar ... , but I think I've spent enough time thinking about this one, and I'm pretty sure this works alright.

Comment: You are right, it should work.  I guess I was looking for it to print [0..1][2..3][4..6][7..10]

Comment: @mgilson Your solution doesn't work for reverse ranges such as `range(8, 5, -1)`. These occur when there are negative numbers in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer yields the correct result, the solution can be obtained using nothing but a few loops and list generators.
More advanced language operators seem inappropriate, since the question is asking about such a simple problem -- generating a few lists.

This solution only works for positive integers.
Handling sequences with negatives is left as an exercise for the reader.

```python
# starting data
nums = [3, 5, 22, 6]

# Generate endpoints for output sequences.
# Note that the first sequence starts specially at 0.
endpoints = [0]
for i in range(len(nums)):
    endpoints.append(endpoints[i] + nums[i])
endpoints[0] = -1

# Generate output sequences.
outseqs = []
for i in range(1, len(endpoints)):
    outseq = [n for n in range(endpoints[i - 1] + 1, endpoints[i] + 1)]
    outseqs.append(outseq)

# Display output sequences.
for i in range(len(outseqs)):
    print outseqs[i]
```

Comment: For `[1,2,3,4]` as input, for example, your code yields `[[0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]`. Instead, it should be `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`

Comment: Yes, now it works. However, your solution suffers as well from the fact that it doesn't work for negative numbers in the input.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions provided so far don't work if there are negative numbers in the input so that ranges in reverse order are required. My solution covers that. Works with Python 2 and 3. Here it is:

```
from itertools import izip

# create the x (=start) and y (=stop) coordinates for the ranges separately
def _get_xs(iterable):
    yield 0
    for i in xrange(1, len(iterable)):
        yield sum(iterable[:i]) + 1

def _get_ys(iterable):
    yield iterable[0]
    for i in xrange(1, len(iterable)):
        yield sum(iterable[:i+1])

def to_ranges(iterable):
    xs = _get_xs(iterable)
    ys = _get_ys(iterable)
    for x, y in izip(xs, ys):
        if x < y:
            step = 1
            y += 1
        elif x > y:
            step = -1
            y -= 1
        else:
            step = 0
        try:
            yield range(x, y, step)
        except ValueError:
            yield [x]
```

Examples:

```
# edge case: instead of malformed ranges such as range(10, 10), put [10] instead

>>> list(to_ranges([1, 2, 3, 4]))
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

>>> list(to_ranges([4, 3, 2, 1]))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10]]

>>> list(to_ranges([4, 3, 2, -1]))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 9, 8]]

>>> list(to_ranges([-4, -3, -2, -1]))
[[0, -1, -2, -3, -4], [-3, -4, -5, -6, -7], [-6, -7, -8, -9], [-8, -9, -10]]

>>> list(to_ranges([-1, -2, -3, -4]))
[[0, -1], [0, -1, -2, -3], [-2, -3, -4, -5, -6], [-5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]]
```